# PHP str_replace with mixed text and variables?

Tags: php

I have a function and within the function I have:

```
$clean_dir = str_replace("temp_images/".$foldername."/output/", "", $dir);
```

$foldername value is outside the function.

When I run the above temp_images/xyz/output remains temp_images/xyz/output, but then I replace temp_images/xyz/output with xyz directly instead of $foldername. then it changes.

How can I insert mixed text with a variable in str_replace?

Thanks

Comment: use global $foldername; inside function to get $foldername variable value if it is outside the function. Can you show the whole code, please.

Comment: `How can I insert mixed text with a variable in str_replace?` -- what do you mean by that? What does `var_dump($foldername);` output? And what do you want the result to be?

Comment: @PannyMonium: Using global variables is widely regarded as a bad practice. Pass the variable as a function parameter instead. See my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19479044/1438393) below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't recommend using global variables. Pass `$foldername` as a function parameter instead:

```
function some_func($foldername) {
    ...
    $clean_dir = str_replace("temp_images/".$foldername."/output/", "", $dir);
    ...
}
```

Comment: I tried it as in function FolderToDropbox($dir, $dropbox_link, $foldername)
 but it didn't work

Comment: @PannyMonium: `didn't work` is not very descriptive.  Add `ini_set('display_errors',1); 
 error_reporting(E_ALL);` to the very top of your script and refresh the page. Do you get any errors?

Comment: Missing argument 3 for FolderToDropbox()

Comment: @PannyMonium: The error is pretty self-explanatory, no? Fix your function call ;)

Comment: Are you brave enough to answer this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19483881/php-remotely-delete-files-on-dropbox-using-php-without-using-an-api   :-)

Answer (score -1):

Pass a variable with the function :

```
function qwerty($foldername){
 ....
 $clean_dir = str_replace("temp_images/".$foldername."/output/", "", $dir);
 ....
}
qwerty("xyz");
```

### Other Way (not good)

use `global $foldername;` inside function to get **$foldername** variable value if it is outside the function. Example :

```
$foldername="xyz";
function qwerty(){
 global $foldername;
 $clean_dir = str_replace("temp_images/".$foldername."/output/", "", $dir);
 ....
}
```

It's not a good practice to use **global** variable. Instead use the 1st example.

Comment: If it's not a good practice, then why include it in your answer? :)

Comment: The user must know the both ways. Sometimes global is needed in desperate times. So other users who sees this answer might find it helpful.

Comment: @Subin I agree, but don't put the bad solution at the top of an answer. Most users will only take that and if it works, they won't give the actual solution a try.