# PHP Remotely delete files on Dropbox using PHP without using an API

Tags: php, dropbox

I have the code below to upload files to Dropbox. Now I'd like to modify the code below to delete certain folders / images on dropbox in a particular folder.

```
<?php
$siteroot = $folder_output; 

$dropbox_email='xxx@xxxxx.com';  //Dropbox username
$dropbox_pass='xxxxxxxxxxxx';   // Dropbox password

include("DropboxUploader.php");

$uploader = new DropboxUploader($dropbox_email, $dropbox_pass);

function FolderToDropbox($dir, $dropbox_link){
    global $foldername;    
    $dropbox_folder = 'Public/';
    $files = scandir($dir);
    foreach($files as $item){
        if($item != '.' && $item != '..'){
            if(is_dir($dir.'/'.$item)) FolderToDropbox($dir.'/'.$item,$dropbox_link);
            else if(is_file($dir.'/'.$item)) {
                $clean_dir = str_replace("temp_images/".$foldername."/output/", "", $dir);
                $dropbox_link->upload($dir.'/'.$item,$dropbox_folder.$clean_dir.'/');  
            } 
        }
    }
}

FolderToDropbox($siteroot,$uploader);

echo 'Copying to Cloud - Success!<br />';


?>
```

Without using an API(just for the sake of trying new things) could I delete certain pictures on my Dropbox.

I tried this code:

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL);

$siteroot = $folder_output; 

$dropbox_email='xxxx@xxxxxxx.com';  //Dropbox username
$dropbox_pass='xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';   // Dropbox password

include("DropboxUploader.php");

$uploader = new DropboxUploader($dropbox_email, $dropbox_pass);

function FolderToDropbox($dir, $dropbox_link){
    global $foldername;    
    $dropbox_folder = 'Public/';
    $files = scandir($dir);
    $dropbox_link->delete($dir.,$dropbox_folder.'/');  
            } 
        }
    }
}
 FolderToDropbox($siteroot,$uploader);
echo 'Copying to Cloud - Success!<br />';

?>
```

No errors and ntohing happens

Comment: Check if the method `$dropbox_link->delete` had capability to delete folders. Coz the parameters you are passing looks like a whole folder and not a file.

Comment: "Without an API" - impossible. You'd at least utilize the API Dropbox offers to access the files.

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra comma and double //. Maybe this might make it work:

```
$dropbox_link->delete($dir.$dropbox_folder);
```

Comment: PHP Warning:  scandir()

Comment: You can remove that line: `$files = scandir($dir);`

Comment: what does `$siteroot = $folder_output; ` output?